# How do I differentiate between a change and removal of model/collection attributes in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to know if there is any event triggered specifically in backbone to differentiate between the change of an attribute value and removal of an attribute in backbone model or collection

Answer (score 1):

No, calling unset on a model attribute just fires a [change event](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-54). If you need to have a differentiated event to hook into, I'd recommend adding a method to the model that wraps an unset call and fires a custom event:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  removeAttribute: function (attr) {
    this.unset('attr', { silent: true });
    this.trigger('attributeRemoved');
  }
});

var newModel = new MyModel({ first: 'foo', second: 'bar' });
newModel.removeAttribute('first');
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `set` and `unset` will fire a `'change'` event. From Backbone documentation:

- **Set**

  > Set a hash of attributes (one or many) on the model. If any of the
  >   attributes change the model's state, a "change" event will be
  >   triggered on the model. Change events for specific attributes are also
  >   triggered, and you can bind to those as well, for example:
  >   change:title, and change:content. You may also pass individual keys
  >   and values
- **Unset**

  > Remove an attribute by deleting it from the internal attributes hash.
  >   Fires a "change" event unless silent is passed as an option.

And if you have a look at [backbone source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js), you will see the following for unset:

```
// Remove an attribute from the model, firing `"change"`. `unset` is a noop
// if the attribute doesn't exist.
unset: function(attr, options) {
  return this.set(attr, void 0, _.extend({}, options, {unset: true}));
},
```

**EDIT**

You can create your own `unset` function replacing the existing one in Backbone.Model, where you can trigger any new events you might need:

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    unset: function(attr, options) {
        options || (options = {});

        //Call unset in Backbone.Model, set silent option also if suppressChangeEvent was set
        var silent = options.silent;
        options.silent = silent || options.suppressChangeEvent;
        var res = Backbone.Model.prototype.unset.apply(this, arguments);

        //trigger unset events if not silent and the attribute was removed
        if (attr == null || silent || !this.hasChanged(attr)) return res;            
        this.trigger('unset:' + attr, this, this._previousAttributes[attr], options);
        this.trigger('unset', this, options);            
        return res;
    }
});
```

I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky099vqr/) so you can see this idea in action. If you test it with the following code:

```
var myModel = new FooModel({key1 : 1, key2: "foo", key3: "a"});
myModel.on("change", function(){ console.log("change triggered"); });
myModel.on("change:key1", function(){ console.log("change for key1 triggered"); });
myModel.on("change:key2", function(){ console.log("change for key2 triggered"); });
myModel.on("unset", function(){ console.log("unset triggered"); });
myModel.on("unset:key1", function(){ console.log("unset for key1 triggered"); });
myModel.on("unset:key2", function(){ console.log("unset for key2 triggered"); });

myModel.unset("key1");
myModel.unset("key2", {suppressChangeEvent: true});
myModel.unset("key3", {silent: true});
myModel.unset("key5");
```

You will see the following output in your console (all events triggered for key1, only unset events triggered for key2 and none if silent or attribute doesn't exists):

```
change for key1 triggered
change triggered
unset for key1 triggered
unset triggered
unset for key2 triggered
unset triggered
```